# MeteorJS - How Send two seperate queries of the same collection from server to client

Tags: mongodb, meteor, server, client

I am trying to send two separate sets of data from the same collection from server to client. Data is being inserted in the collection on a set interval of 30 seconds. One set of data sent to the client must return all documents over the course of the current day on an hourly basis, while the other set of data simply sends the most recent entry in the collection. I have a graph that needs to display hourly data, as well as fields that need to display the most recent record every 30 seconds, however, I cannot seem to decouple these two data sets. The query for the most recent entry seems to always overwrite the query for the hourly data when attempting to access the data on the client. So my question summed up is: How does one send two separate sets of data of the same collection from server to client, and then access these two separate sets independently on the client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is simple, you cannot!

The server is always answering to client with a result set that the client asked for. So, if the client needs two separate (different) result sets, then the client must fire up two different queries. Queries that request hourly data OR last (newest) entry.

Answer (score 0):

Use `added`, `changed`, `removed` to modify the results from the two queries so that they are "transformed" into different fields. https://docs.meteor.com/api/pubsub.html#Subscription-added

However, this is probably not your issue. You are almost certainly using the same string as the `name` argument of your `Meteor.publish` call, or you are accidentally `Meteor.subscribe`-ing to the same `Meteor.publish` twice.

Make two separate `Meteor.publish` names, one for the most recent and one for the hourly data. Subscribe to each of them separately. The commenter is incorrect.